# Running multiple scenes in parallel in Phaser 3.20.1

Tags: javascript, frameworks, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a score display that displays above my game and shows current scores. I have tried:
`this.scene.call("scene1", "scene2");`
This did *not* work.

I can run one scene by using:
`this.scene.start("scene1");` but `this.scene.start("scene1", "scene2");` only starts the first scene.

Is there a method I can use that will start 2 scenes in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to use `this.scene.launch("scene");` from inside another scene.

Example is [here.](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cscenes%5Cmultiple%20scenes%20from%20instances.js)

Comment: you should also be able to use [game.scene.add](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.SceneManager.html#add__anchor) per each individual scene, with autoStart set to `true`

Comment: I did not know that! Thank you